# Jquery Terminal always gets focused upon

Tags: jquery, html, terminal, jquery-terminal

Whenever the page loads, the page scrolls down to the [jquery terminal](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal) directly. I want to disable this feature and haven't been able to do it for quite a while.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can use option `enabled: false`, that way terminal will be disabled when creating. http://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php#enabled

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton! I have trying to get a hang of it for quite a while. It did work indeed . And also thanks for your amazing work. Keep it up! :)

Comment: hey @jcubic , although it does disable the terminal and does not get scrolled down to it on page refresh, it does get scrolled down to when the html demo file is opened for the first time ( the terminal cursor isn't visible which implies that the terminal is disabled). Any way to disable it from scrolling down altogether?

Comment: Just fixed that. It was happening cause the demo code that I was using had the body of the html page as the terminal input class and hence it got focused upon. The moment I created another div and passed it to the terminal code as the terminal output location, it got fixed. I'm not sure whether I have been able to express myself correctly here but the crux is that problem is now solved :)